# Hosting Silverlight widget from local file system

Tags: silverlight

I'm trying to host a remote Silverlight widget in an html file that will exist locally on the hard drive, but whenever I open the html file, the Silverlight content does not show up.  If I move the file to a web server and then access it through http, it works perfectly.  I figured out (or at least I assume) that the widget is trying to make a call back to the web server but it's failing because of the [cross zone restrictions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189008(VS.95).aspx) in SL 2+.  I've also seen a few reports from users talking about running into this issue when debugging from a local file.  My question is, how can I tell for sure that this is the issue going on/what tools might I use to verify my hypothesis?

Additionally, (knowing full well that there are elevation of privileges security concerns to take into account) is there any way that I could declare the web services the widget calls as safe (for instance adding to the trusted sites) in such a way that Silverlight would be able to perform the calls without the security exceptions?

An example of a widget I'm talking about is below:

```
<object 
    type="application/x-silverlight-2" 
    data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," 
    width="400" height="400">
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40624.0" />
    <param name="background" value="#141414" />
    <param name="splashScreenSource"
      value="http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/Widget/3.2009.1014.0/Splash.xaml" />
    <param name="source"
      value="http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/Widget/3.2009.1014.0/HardRock.Memorabilia.Silverlight.Widget.xap" />
    <param name="enableHtmlAccess" value="true" />
    <param name="initParams" value="item=034739" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=149156&v=3.0.40624.0">
        <img src="http://memorabilia.hardrock.com/Widget/3.2009.1014.0/Ping.gif?type=install&item=034739" 
          style="background:#141414
           url(http://content.memorabilia.hardrock.com/Assets/Images/widget/034739.jpg)
           no-repeat center;margin:0;padding:0;border:0;" 
          width="400" height="400" />
    </a>
</object>
```

Comment: Is this Silverlight control one that you are permitted to host within your own local file? IOW, is it yours or do you have permission to use it?

Comment: Not submitting as answer because I'm not sure, but have you looked into the "client access policy" file? http://www.silverlighttutorials.com/?p=148

Comment: The Silverlight control is not my control.  In the example above, it's hosted by memorabilia.hardrock.com and is provided by them as a widget including embed code.  They do allow cross domain calls (I found the client access policy file at http://hardrock.com/crossdomain.xml and when I just tossed the test html file on a web server the content downloaded as expected), but from the documentation this looks like it's more of an issue with cross zone calls, and I haven't seen a way to configure that to be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of a cross protocol violation - a page with a file:// protocol cannot access assets with an http:// protocol.  This also helps protect your your computer from accessed by a malicious Silverlight application.

Comment: Whether it's cross zone or cross protocol, without access to the SL control or code, do you know of any way to verify the error?  I don't see any errors thrown from the browser, and when I use fiddler I don't see anything in the traffic that looks useful.  Perhaps said another way, is there any way to diagnose this issue other than logic and general knowledge of the access policy limitations.
Furthermore, I understand why this helps protect my computer.  However, if I were so inclined, is there any way that I could individually choose to make my computer less secure and make this work?